# How do I call function results into a tkinter window listbox thats in another function?

Tags: python, tkinter

Can anyone help me complete this code? I am trying to pass the results of a function in this case it's a nested function called "processFile" to it's parent function within a tkinter frame. I only recently started using classes, so I still have a lot to learn and I'm sure you can imminently point out that what I've done so far is not best practice or efficient.

I tried making processFile a regular function in the class, and a nested function as seen in the code below. The majority of errors I get are,

line 24, in 
    button1 = Button(ouUpdate, text='Open File', command=lambda: processFile(self, filename))
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined

I understand why, and I realize that using a listbox I have to first convert the resulting string to a list, but I need help with making this work.

NOTE: I will eventually write the csv reader to the processFile function to read csv results into the listbox, but I'm just trying to get started for now.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

class GUI:
    def mainPage(self):
        home = Frame(root)
        home.place(relwidth=1, relheigh=1)
        label = Label(home, text='Cyber Database Console', bg='#ccffcc', font=('Arial', 18))
        label.place(relx=0 , rely=0, relheigh=0.1, relwidth=1)
        button1 = Button(home, text='OU Update', command=lambda: self.ouUpdate())
        button1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.2, relheigh=0.05, relwidth=0.2)
        button2 = Button(home, text='VID Update', command=lambda: self.vIDUpdate())
        button2.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.3, relheigh=0.05, relwidth=0.2)


    def ouUpdate(self):
        ouUpdate = Frame(root)
        ouUpdate.place(relwidth=1, relheigh=1)
        label = Label(ouUpdate, text='Database OU Update Console', bg='#ccffcc', font=('Arial', 18))
        label.place(relx=0 , rely=0, relheigh=0.1, relwidth=1)
        button1 = Button(ouUpdate, text='Back', command=lambda: self.mainPage())
        button1.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheigh=0.05, relwidth=0.2)
        button1 = Button(ouUpdate, text='Open File', command=lambda: processFile(self, filename))
        button1.place(relx=0, rely=0.4, relheigh=0.05, relwidth=0.2)
        listing = Listbox(ouUpdate)
        listing.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6, relheigh=0.1, relwidth=0.5)

        def processFile(self, filename):
            filename = askopenfilename()
            return filename

    def vIDUpdate(self):
        vIDUpdate = Frame(root)
        vIDUpdate.place(relwidth=1, relheigh=1)
        label = Label(vIDUpdate, text='Database V-ID Console', bg='#ccffcc', font=('Arial', 18))
        label.place(relx=0 , rely=0, relheigh=0.1, relwidth=1)
        button1 = Button(vIDUpdate, text='Back', command=lambda: self.mainPage())
        button1.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheigh=0.05, relwidth=0.2)


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, heigh=500, width=600)
canvas.pack()

begin = GUI()

begin.mainPage()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you don't need `filename` in `processFile(self, filename):`  to get `filename` from this function. `def processFile(self): return askopenfilename()` but Button can't get result so better assing this to class variable `def processFile(self): self.filename = askopenfilename()`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `filename` in `processFile(self, filename):` to get value from function.

```
 def processFile(self):
     return askopenfilename()

 ... command=lambda:processFile(self)
```

You would need it only if you want to send filename to function.

But `Button` can't get this result and assign to variable so better do it inside function

```
 def processFile(self):
     self.filename = askopenfilename()
```

and then you can use this variable in other methods in class.

But you can't past it to backt to `ouUpdate` because this funtion is executed and finished at start - before you even see window. You should use filename directly in this funtion

```
 def processFile(self):
     self.filename = askopenfilename()
     data = open(self.filename).read()
     # ... process data ...
```

---

Instead of `command=lambda: self.mainPage()` you can do `command=self.mainPage`
 (without `lambda` and `()`)

The same with other

`command=lambda: self.ouUpdate()` -> `command=self.ouUpdate`

`command=lambda: self.vIDUpdate()` -> `command=self.vIDUpdate`

If you put `processFile(self)` as normal method in class, not nested then you can also use `command=self.processFile`